# filter condition with rx Swift

Tags: swift, filter, rx-swift

I want to map a dict 
and flatMap to return a new Observable.
I am trying Observable as I might either 1 single object or an array of object.

```
func fetchRibsList() -> Observable<[LCLRibAccount]>  {
        return provider.rxDict(service: .fetchRibsList)
            .map({ (dict, _) -> [String: Any] in
                return dict
            })
            .filter({ dict -> Bool in
                dict["ribs"] != nil
            })
            .filter({ dict -> Bool in
                dict["rib"] != nil
            })
            .flatMap({ dict -> Observable<Any> in

                //return either list of ribs or 1 single rib
                if let ribs = dict["ribs"] as? [String: Any] {
                    return Observable.just(LCLRib.parseAccountList(with: ribs))
                }

                if let rib = dict["rib"] as? [String: Any] {
                    return Observable.just(LCLRib.parseRib(with: rib))
                }

                return Observable.empty()
            })
    }
```

is it possible to include a condition with 2 flatMap and return an array or 1 single object
the issue is that I need to be specific with the Observable type:

this is the error I get : **Cannot convert return expression of type 'Observable' to return type 'Observable<[LCLRibAccount]>'**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your function's return type `func fetchRibsList() -> Observable<[LCLRibAccount]>`. It expects Observable of an array. Perhaps you can wrap single object in a array. Like this:

```
func fetchRibsList() -> Observable<[LCLRibAccount]>  {
    return provider.rxDict(service: .fetchRibsList)
        .map({ (dict, _) -> [String: Any] in
            return dict
        })
        .filter({ dict -> Bool in
            dict["ribs"] != nil
        })
        .filter({ dict -> Bool in
            dict["rib"] != nil
        })
        .flatMap({ dict -> Observable<[LCLRibAccount]> in

            //return either list of ribs or 1 single rib
            if let ribs = dict["ribs"] as? [String: Any] {
                return Observable.just(LCLRib.parseAccountList(with: ribs))
            }

            if let rib = dict["rib"] as? [String: Any] {
                return Observable.just([LCLRib.parseRib(with: rib)]) //wrap single object in array
            }

            return Observable.empty()
        })
}
```